# GDI+ PenAlignmentInset seems to be different than GDI PS_INSIDEFRAME

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, gdi

I've encountered a strange issue when trying to draw rectangles with GDI+, but I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

The GDI+ pen alignment setting, `PenAlignmentInset`, seems to not work properly when the pen width is 1.

I've created a minimally reproducible demo below in order to illustrate the point.  First, a red GDI rectangle is drawn using `PS_INSIDEFRAME`, and then a blue GDI+ rectangle is drawn right over it using `PenAlignmentInset`. When the pen widths are 4 and 2, for example, the GDI+ rectangle completely covers the red GDI rectangle, as you’d expect. Their alignment corresponds. But when the pen width is 1, the GDI+ rectangle’s border placement is incorrect, I believe, and part of the red GDI rectangle is thus visible.

[image: Result]

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"MyClass";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"GDI+ bug demo",               // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));

        // Demonstrating a width of 4 units
        {
            HPEN hpen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 4, RGB(255, 0, 0));
            HGDIOBJ hgdiobjOldPen = SelectObject(hdc, hpen);
            Rectangle(hdc, 50, 50, 150, 150);

            SelectObject(hdc, hgdiobjOldPen);
            DeleteObject(hpen);

            Gdiplus::Graphics gfx(hdc);
            Gdiplus::Pen pen(Gdiplus::Color(0, 0, 255), 4);
            pen.SetAlignment(Gdiplus::PenAlignmentInset);
            gfx.DrawRectangle(&pen, 50, 50, 100, 100);
        }

        // Demonstrating a width of 2 units

        {
            HPEN hpen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 2, RGB(255, 0, 0));
            HGDIOBJ hgdiobjOldPen = SelectObject(hdc, hpen);
            Rectangle(hdc, 200, 50, 300, 150);

            SelectObject(hdc, hgdiobjOldPen);
            DeleteObject(hpen);

            Gdiplus::Graphics gfx(hdc);
            Gdiplus::Pen pen(Gdiplus::Color(0, 0, 255), 2);
            pen.SetAlignment(Gdiplus::PenAlignmentInset);
            gfx.DrawRectangle(&pen, 200, 50, 100, 100);
        }

        // Demonstrating a width of 1 unit - PROBLEM !!!!
        {
            HPEN hpen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 1, RGB(255, 0, 0));
            HGDIOBJ hgdiobjOldPen = SelectObject(hdc, hpen);
            Rectangle(hdc, 350, 50, 450, 150);

            SelectObject(hdc, hgdiobjOldPen);
            DeleteObject(hpen);

            Gdiplus::Graphics gfx(hdc);
            Gdiplus::Pen pen(Gdiplus::Color(0, 0, 255), 1);
            pen.SetAlignment(Gdiplus::PenAlignmentInset);
            gfx.DrawRectangle(&pen, 350, 50, 100, 100);
        }

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Does anyone know why that might be happening?  Thank you for any input.

Comment: maybe it's due to antialiasing? How about setting a different smoothing mode? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-antialiasing-with-lines-and-curves-about

Comment: @9dan Per your suggestion, I just tried calling `gfx.SetSmoothingMode(Gdiplus::SmoothingModeAntiAlias);` (with several different settings) before drawing the last rectangle, but it didn't have any effect.  Thank you for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: Not sure but, it can be due to the internal floating-point errors in Gdi+.

Comment: I've looked [at documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-setting-pen-width-and-alignment-use) and the example there exhibits exactly the same problem. Right and bottom parts of the line with 1px width are actually outside of the rectangle. While an attempt to fix things by adjusting coordinates by 0.5f by calling `gfx.TranslateTransform(-0.5f, -0.5f, Gdiplus::MatrixOrderAppend);` fixes right and bottom parts of the line, it breaks top and left parts and even causes a gap to appear in the corner. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNfDg.png